# how to create URL extractor like facebook share

Tags: php, python, facebook

i need to extract data from url 
like title , description ,and any vedios images in the given url 
like facebook share button

like this :
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.wired.com&t=Test

regards

Answer (score 5):

[Embed.ly](http://www.embed.ly) has a nice api for exactly this purpose. Their api returns the site's oEmbed data if available - otherwise, it attempts to extract a summary of the page like Facebook.

Comment: Best solution by far, but limits the users, then again if your website has enough users where Emdedly would charge you, you would be making a well enough amount of money to cover the $10-$100 a month your gonna pay for the 50,000 queries per month, the free is only 5,000 queries per month. Just a little information about Embedly before going to it. All in all, best answer for using a plugin to solve the issue. Other then that cURL would be the only other way if your doing it from scratch.

Answer (score 4):

Use something like [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to get the page and then something like [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to parse it and extract the elements you want.

Comment: thanx, plz can you also provide me with something work in python also.

Answer (score 2):

If the web site has support for [oEmbed](http://www.oembed.com/), that's easier and more robust than scraping HTML:

> oEmbed is a format for allowing an embedded representation of a URL on third party sites. The simple API allows a website to display embedded content (such as photos or videos) when a user posts a link to that resource, without having to parse the resource directly.

oEmbed is supported by sites like YouTube and Flickr.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on a project for this issue, it is not as easy as writing an html parser and expecting sites to be 'semantical'. Especially extracting videos and finding auto-play parameters are killing. You can check the project in http://www.embedify.me, which has also fb-style url preview script. As I see, embed.ly and oembed are passive parser, they need the sites to support them, so called providers, the approach is quite different than fb does.

Comment: Thank you. Works great. A downloadable, self-hosted version would be nice too.

Answer (score -1):

While I was looking for a similar functionality, I came across a jQuery + PHP demo of the url extract feature of Facebook messages:
http://www.99points.info/2010/07/facebook-like-extracting-url-data-with-jquery-ajax-php/

Instead of using an HTML DOM parser, it works with simple regular expressions. It looks for title, description and img tags. Hence, the image extraction doesn't perform well with a lot of websites, which use CSS for images. Also, Facebook looks first at its own meta tags and then at the classic description tag of HTML but it illustrates well the principe.