# Facebook like link data extractor

Tags: facebook, url, extract

I'm seeking a lib that takes a URL and returns back useful information like:

- Title
- Description
- List of images

Anything around?

Comment: [take a look @ this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999535/how-to-create-url-extractor-like-facebook-share)

Comment: try this http://www.99points.info/2010/07/facebook-like-extracting-url-data-with-jquery-ajax-php/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out the REST API links.preview method - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/links.preview/

You can also test out a few URLs to see if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Embed has a nice api for exactly this purpose. [link](http://embed.ly/)

Answer (score 0):

This one made my day: http://www.embedify.me/

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can send ajax request to a php file which gets contents of the url using file_get_contents() function and returns it to ajax. Then we can extract whatever we want from this data response. 
For explanation, live demo and script download follow herehttp://www.voidtricks.com/extracting-url-data-like-facebook/